# Bulk create on related models using csv

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use `bulk_create` in order to add objects to related models. Here i'm fetching the csv file through post request which contains required fields. As of now I can add items to models which is unrelated using the csv file and `bulk_create` and it's working.

```
class BulkAPI(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        paramFile = io.TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['requirementfile'].file)
        dict1 = csv.DictReader(paramFile)
        list_of_dict = list(dict1)
        objs = [
            ManpowerRequirement(
                project=row['project'],
                position=row['position'],
                quantity=row['quantity'],
                project_location=row['project_location'],
                requested_date=row['requested_date'],
                required_date=row['required_date'],
                employment_type=row['employment_type'],
                duration=row['duration'],
                visa_type=row['visa_type'],
                remarks=row['remarks'],
            )
            for row in list_of_dict
        ]
        try:
            msg = ManpowerRequirement.objects.bulk_create(objs)
            returnmsg = {"status_code": 200}
            print('imported successfully')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error While Importing Data: ', e)
            returnmsg = {"status_code": 500}

        return JsonResponse(returnmsg)
```

My models are:

```
class ManpowerRequirement(models.Model):


    project = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    project_location = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    requested_date = models.DateField()
    required_date = models.DateField()
    employment_type = models.CharField(max_length=60,choices = EMPLOYMENT_TYPE_CHOICES, 
        default = 'Permanent')
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    visa_type = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    remarks = models.TextField(blank = True , null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.project
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Manpower_Requirement"


class Fulfillment(models.Model):


    candidate_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    manpower_requirement = models.ForeignKey(ManpowerRequirement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    passport_number = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length=60)
    subcontract_vendors = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True , null=True ,default='')
    joined_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True, default = '')
    remarks = models.TextField( blank = True,null = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.candidate_name
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Fulfillment"

class FulfillmentStatus(models.Model):


    fulfillment = models.ForeignKey(Fulfillment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    status_date = models.DateField()
    remarks = models.TextField( blank = True, null = True )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fulfillment.candidate_name
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "FulfillmentStatus"
```

I don't know how to do the same using `bulk_create` for `Fulfillment` and `FulfillmentStatus` models which are related to `ManpowerRequirement`. Csv file which I recieve in order to bulkcreate for `Fulfillment` consists of all the fields of `ManpowerRequirement` and all fields of `Fulfillment` and `FulfillmentStatus` excluding the foreign keys and id fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For related models we can do like this

```
class FulfillmentAPI(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        paramFile = io.TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['fulfillmentfile'].file)
        dict1 = csv.DictReader(paramFile)
        list_of_dict = list(dict1)
        objs = [
                Fulfillment(
                    manpower_requirement=ManpowerRequirement.objects.get(project=row['project'], position=row['position'], quantity=row['quantity'], requested_date=row['requested_date'],),
                    remarks=row['remarks'],
                    candidate_name=row['candidate_name'],
                    passport_number=row['passport_number'],
                    joined_date=row['joined_date'],
                    subcontract_vendors=row['subcontract_vendors'],
                )
               
                for row in list_of_dict
            ]
        try:
            msg = Fulfillment.objects.bulk_create(objs)
            returnmsg = {"status_code": 200}
            print('imported successfully')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error While Importing Data: ', e)
            returnmsg = {"status_code": 500}

        return JsonResponse(returnmsg)
```

Comment: here you're doing a query for each `ManpowerRequirement` object

Answer (score 0):

in the past I had the same problem; I solved in that way

Assuming that in a single CSV row you have data for all models I'd go for

1. create a mapping between the main model and the linked ones (you could use row index as key
2. use `bulk_create()` on the main model
3. iterate the dict and use `bulk_create()` for the linked modules

```py
items = []
mrs = []
for row in list_of_dict:
    mr = ManpowerRequirement(...)
    mrs.append(mr)

    f = ManpowerRequirement(...)

    fs = FulfillmentStatus(...)

    items.append((mr, f, fs))

# create all Manpower Requirements
ManpowerRequirements.objects.bulk_create(mrs)

a = []
for mr, f, fs in items:
   f.manpower_requirement = mr

   a.append(f)

# create all Fulfillments
Fulfillment.objects.bulk_create(a)

a = []
for mr, f, fs in items:
   fs.fulfillment = f

   a.append(fs)

# create all FulfillmentStatus
FulfillmentStatus.objects.bulk_create(a)
```

not sure if you can do some optimization in looping but it should solve the problem with just 3 queries

Comment: does `bulk_create()` work on `Fulfillment` without primary key of `ManpowerRequirement`?

Comment: after the `bulk_create` the `ManpowerRequirement` instances have the pk set. so `f.manpower_requirement = mr` in the second loop does the trick

Comment: i don't get this, is there any doc or link to know about it more?

Comment: about what? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create is the `bulk_create` doc, I forgot to mention that I used PostgreSQL and it automatically populates pk

Comment: thank you I solved mine taking some of info from here

Comment: If you found the solution, post here or check my answer as the right one. In this way other people will find how to solve the problem